# how to authenticate your application and send meeting invitations for zoom in angular application

Tags: angular, zoom-sdk

i am currently working on a job applying website similar to linkedin so whenever a job seeker applies for a job I as an admin (from the dashboard) can either reject or accept and before that I have to send them a zoom invite link for having a brief initial interview.

[image]

I am using asp.net zero template with angular for SPA. Any help would be appreciated.